# How to test a Ajax FAIL handler

Tags: php, ajax

I am rewriting some old JS/php functions using the new handlers for Ajax calls.
The 'done' and 'always' are ok; they do what expected.
Question (possibly silly, sorry): how can I test the 'fail' part? Or, asked in a different way, when this handler is activated?
This is the JS function used for testing:

```js
$("#btn1").on('click',function(event)  {
 var ob=[];

  $.get({
      url: "php/test.php?code=5",
  }).done(function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data);
        var id=response[0];       
      ob = response[1]; 
  }).fail(function (jqXHR,status,err) {
     alert("Error in function");
  }).always(function () {
       alert ("Done!");    
  })
});
```

and this is the called PHP function:

```js
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "me";
$password = "mypass";
$db_name = "invalid"; //not existing DB
$code= $_GET['code'];

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password,$db_name);  //here the error
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Code='".$code."'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id  = $row[ID];

$list = [
    "Name" => "John",
    "Surname" => "Smith"
];

$res = array($id, $list);
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```

You see that the DB access can not be performed since credentials are wrong, so I expect to receive back some sort of errors, to be intercepted by 'fail'
This does not happen and I get a null (ID) and the list.

Do I misunderstand the 'fail' meaning?

Answer (score 1):

You should return a suitable [HTTP code](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html). You can do so using [`http_response_code`](http://www.php.net/http_response_code):

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  http_response_code(401);
  die;
}
```

Any non-200 error code should result in the fail handler getting triggered.

If you want to catch any error that might be generated by your code, you can make use of [`set_error_handler`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and [`set_exception_handler`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php:):

```
set_error_handler(function (int $errno , string $errstr, string $errfile, int $errline, array $errcontext) {
  // Log error...
  http_response_code(500);
});

set_exception_handler(function (\Exception $exception) {
  // Log error...
  http_response_code(500);
});
```

I used the 500 (Internal Server Error) code for the example, but you could compute a more appropriate error code depending on the error/exception you got.

Comment: This is clear, ok. But, this means I have to explicitly intercept all possible errors and manually raise an error code; I thought that any computation error (excluding syntax) automatically generate a fail (i.e. SQL errors due to invalid data, division by 0, out-of-bounds,..).  Not a big help (the fail, I mean) but I will find a way to use it

Comment: @Orionis See my last edit for a way to automatically catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

The fail will be triggered when your server response http code is not 200, such as 500 server error or runtime exception.

To test fail scenarios, you can simply throw some exception and leave it unhandled.

Or a more sophisticated choice could be fiddler, which is a debugging proxy and you can override the response to anything you want.